# Django getting error: "Reverse accessor for" in Models

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to create a db model using django inspect db and it is generating all the models but I am getting error.

I am using this command to generate db models for existing database:

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

It is generating models accurately but in fileds such as this:

```
create_uid = models.ForeignKey('self', models.DO_NOTHING,db_column='create_uid', blank=True, null=True)
write_uid = models.ForeignKey('self',models.DO_NOTHING,  db_column='write_uid', blank=True, null=True)
```

I am getting error:

```
polls.ResUsers.create_uid: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'ResUsers.create_uid' clashes with reverse accessor for 'ResUsers.write_uid'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'ResUsers.create_uid' or 'ResUsers.write_uid'.
polls.ResUsers.write_uid: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'ResUsers.write_uid' clashes with reverse accessor for 'ResUsers.create_uid'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'ResUsers.write_uid' or 'ResUsers.create_uid'.
```

I am adding related names like this:

```
create_uid = models.ForeignKey('self', models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='create_uid',db_column='create_uid', blank=True, null=True)
```

What should I do in order to use generated models. I am using postgres.

I am updating my question one of the answer worked for me when I am using it like this:

```
create_uid = models.ForeignKey(
    'self',
    models.DO_NOTHING,
    db_column='create_uid',
    related_name='created_items',
    blank=True,
    null=True
)
```

In one other model class when I am using this code like this:

```
create_uid = models.ForeignKey(
    'ResUsers',
    models.DO_NOTHING,
    db_column='create_uid',
    related_name='created_items',
    blank=True,
    null=True
)
```

I am getting the error:

```
polls.ResUsers.create_uid: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'ResUsers.create_uid' clashes with reverse accessor for 'SurveyUserInput.create_uid'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'ResUsers.create_uid' or 'SurveyUserInput.create_uid'.
```

Comment: The `related_name` is the name of the relation in *reverse*, so normally it is *not* the same as the name of the relation. Since you here make a reference to `'self'`, normally it should not work either.

Comment: There are many modeles like this how can I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**`related_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) is the name of the relation in reverse. So it is meant to access all model objects with as `create_uid`/`write_uid` the object. This can result in a `QuerySet` of zero, one or more elements.

Therefore the `related_name`s of two `ForeignKey`s to the same model, can *not* be the same, since that would make the model ambiguous. Since your `ForeignKey`s refer to the `'self'` model, you can not even given these the name of a field that already exists.

You thus might want to give the relations a name like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    create_uid = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        models.DO_NOTHING,
        db_column='create_uid',
        related_name='created_items',
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    write_uid = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        models.DO_NOTHING,
        db_column='write_uid',
        related_name='written_items',
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
```

Comment: It is working for me but when I am using same code where self is not there I am getting error: Reverse accessor for 'ResUsers.create_uid' clashes with reverse accessor for 'SurveyUserInput.create_uid'. Se updated question.

Comment: @NilaySingh: yes, you will need to create other `related_names`, as said before, the related name is the name of a relation from the *target* model to the one where you define it, and these should be unique.